# Mount local folder as volume using Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, mount, mounted-volumes

I'm looking for a way to mount a Local folder as a Volume in OSX. Searching so far hasn't got any results. I want to do this programatically via Swift. For instance, I want to mount `/Users/shoaib/Test` to `/Volumes/MyVolume` which can be accessed via the Finder.

Comment: This question in its current form is probably too broad. Which exactly method do want to use to bind a directory to directory? Maybe using NFS?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `LoopbackFS`. It's an example implementation of the `osxfuse` framework, that does exactly what you want. [It requires the installation of FUSE for OS X.](https://osxfuse.github.io/)

It's written in Objective C, but porting it to Swift shouldn't be too hard. In fact, it's exactly what I'm currently doing for a project. Hopefully (if I have the time), I'll be finished by the end of the week, and I'll post what I've made.

Comment: @Shoaib If you still need this, I'm done a rudimentary port of LoopbackFS to Swift